# Where does memu android simulator save applications files?

Tags: emulators

I know that most Android phones save apk files and applications in the `android/data` folder but when I enter there is none of my already installed applications. Is there anywhere can I find them?

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP account is deleted and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

C:\User Name\Download\MEmu Download\